# Accessing SANs through Application on the cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, san

I am preparing to make a project "Accessing SANS through application on the cloud"

the objective of the project is deploy a SAN in our company and allow users to upload and use data through application stored at Google App Engine.

Is this achieveable? if yes then how could application deploy on google server access my company's network for data?

Is the project too hard? Plz advice..

Answer (score 2):

The App Engine only allows http(s) communication, your SAN will need to have some sort of web server that allows deploying file using some sort of a PUT or POST handler.
If not the SAN you will have to implement that web web server inside your organization, that web server will need to be open to the internet (but have a security layer to prevent from anyone to access it)